# Завершение потока (Thread.Abort)

Tags: c++-cli

Я сделал так, вроде все учел, но не работает, в чем трабла?

```
try {
    int numThreads = Convert::ToInt32(numericUpDown1->Text);

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        myThread->Name = String::Format("Thread {0}", i + 1);
        // Wait a random amount of time before starting next thread.
        myThread->Abort();
    }
}
catch(ThreadAbortException ^ ex)
{
    Thread::ResetAbort();
}
```

Comment: я не знаком с параллельным программированием, но у меня возник вопрос: где Вы запускаете поток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишете "не работает", но, к сожалению, не указали, какого поведения ожидаете. При такой постановке вопроса на него можно ответить только другим вопросом: Что именно не работает?

Могу *предположить*, что не ловится ожидаемое исключение  `ThreadAbortException`. Исключение `ThreadAbortException` возникает в том потоке, для которого вызывается `Abort` (а не в том, в котором вызвано). Поэтому ловить исключение следует в том потоке, который вы прерываете (переменная `myThread`). Из приведенного кода совершенно непонятно, что это за поток.

Comment: ну допустим при нажатие кнопки пусть numThreads=10    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        myThread->Name = String::Format("Thread {0}", i + 1);
        myThread->Start();
    }
запустилось 10 потоков как их остановить? 
вот ошибка 
Дополнительные сведения: Это свойство уже назначено и не может изменяться.

Comment: все уже разобрался спс